# How to print a column's content recursively

Tags: linux, date, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to capture the content of one column and print it if condition is met. Multiple row can have valid condition. I want to print them all.

## Explanation:

```
cat fileName  


name1 Oct 20 user1@user.com    
name2 Oct 21 user2@user.com    
name3 Oct 19 user3@user.com    
name3 Oct 21 user4@user.com
```

So if the birthday is matching with the current date then get the first name of the user(s) and send it to a file2, file2 will be sent to user through mail. This funcnality can be easily done for one user, However from more then one user I am not able to sum it up.

So for today, my script should write following lines into a file.

Happy birthday Name1 NAme2

Which I will be sending as HTML to Group ID.

Comment: What's your approach? First show some code.

Comment: Edit, I am using this birthday analogy for explaining the issue.

Comment: 1. Check the current date.
2. Search for current data in the CSV file.
3. If the match is made (grep -q) ,then mode to point#4 else sleep for 24 hour and remain in infinite while loop. 
4.grep for the number of match, if only one match is found then ...just send the mail.
5.If more then one match is found in CSV, HERE I AM LOST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date` with the `%b %d` format to get the current date, then use `grep` to extract matching lines. Use `cut` to extract the first column. Assign the result to an array:

```
names=($( grep "$(date '+%b %d')" fileName | cut -f1 -d' '))
echo "Happy birthday ${names[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v "Datum=$(date '+%b %d')" '
   ! Use $3 { List=List " " $1 }
   END { if( List !~ /^$/ ) printf "Happy birthday %s\n", List > "File.2" }
   ' YourFile
```

File.2 will receive the test + list of user if there is at least one name with the corresponding date. Up to you to send the file (don't forget to delete any occurence before starting the awk )